# Android kills Activity, but not app itself

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, android-lifecycle

Assume this activities flow: A->B->[C]. Current active activity is [C]

If there is an interruption (phone call, home button, etc) [C] is stopped

Later it will be restarted, unless Android kills entire app process

So steps in [C] lifecycle are pause->stop->(phone call)->restart->start->.... I miss few, this is not important; the important thing is that Android does not kill [C] instance

Question is when can it happen that Android will kill Activity (destroy), but keep app process alive?

tnx

Comment: It's usually best not to try to figure out the circumstances (there are many, and vary from device to device) but rather to learn the life cycle intimately and code the callback methods accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The process life cycle is not tied to the Activity life cycle.

You can have many Activities within one Application - your Application tends to stick around until the system runs low on memory or the user kills it. Roughly speaking, your Application life cycle is similar to the process life cycle.

Activities on the other hand can be destroyed by the system quite often.